# MYSQL interval query SQL injection

Tags: php, mysql

I have this simple MYSQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date > now() - INTERVAL $hours HOUR
```

`$hours` is a PHP GET variable. Do I have to do any check on this variable before using it in the query to avoid SQL injection or is it secure enough? I use PDO statements

Comment: Prepared statements are enough.

Comment: If you substitute directly into the SQL string, then you are at risk for injection.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes.i substitute directly. Can I use bind with this variable? Like `INTERVAL :hours`

Comment: @MichaelSamuel . . . No.  You can bind the number but you will need to use a `case` statement for the interval type.  Or, just check in your code before hand that the interval type is valid.

Comment: oh sorry...forgot to include the hour in the query. The type is fixed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would be good:

`$sth = $Db->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE date > now() - INTERVAL :hours"); $sth->execute(array(':hours'=>$hours,':secondThing'=>$variable));`

That's a way to esacpe your strings. This can be different from your code but the array in the execute and query will be the same (if you use PDO.)

Answer (score 0):

Use prepared statements

See [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Maybe you are getting variables directly from $_POST or $_GET

$unsafe_variable = $_POST['user_input'];

Comment: i already said in the question that i use prepared statements (PDO) :)